# Enable xelatex in Latex Workshops for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, tex, xelatex

I have a template, which defines all the typesetting recommendations for thesis, but it uses xelatex for compilation. I want to continue using VS Code with Latex Workshops, question is how to change compiler to xelatex from pdflatex. The last one cause next error log:

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.sty:45: Fatal Package fontspec Error: The 
fontspec package requires either XeTeX or
(fontspec)                      LuaTeX.
(fontspec)                      
(fontspec)                      You must change your typesetting engine to,
(fontspec)                      e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"instead of
(fontspec)                      "latex" or "pdflatex".
```

Answer (score 80):

The simplest solution found in issues [here](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/514), but in more common formulation:

Copying the content, simply go to <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Extensions</kbd> → <kbd>LaTeX</kbd> (meaning LaTeX is LaTeX workshops), find gear-wheel button with name `Manage`, then find in the list link to `settings.json` under any tag, open and type next:

```
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [{
    "name": "latexmk",
    "command": "latexmk",
    "args": [
        "-xelatex",
        "-synctex=1",
        "-interaction=nonstopmode",
        "-file-line-error",
        "%DOC%"
    ]
}],
```

Reloading the VSCode may be needed.

Also `setting.json` file could be found in `C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`.

Comment: In addition, you could also extend the recipes with xelatex, following the answer in  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478865/vs-code-latex-workshop-custom-recipes-file-location with slight modifications. Note however, that you may have to include the default recipes/tools in addition to the new ones to not just overwrite them only. So you can keep both "normal" latex and xelatex.

Comment: If you have `xelatex` installed as a CLI on your machine, use it as a command directly.

Answer (score 53):

Use [magic comments](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Compile#magic-comments)

add the following line to the beginning of your document.

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
```

To enable magic comments, change the setting [`forceRecipeUsage`](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/3027) to `false`.

Comment: This is the most reliable option. Worked for me when nothing else did

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, being general purpose

Comment: This is not related to enabling xelatex. You are still using pdflatex.

Comment: You should write `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex` 'cause you want to enable it! Edited code: `% !TEX program = xelatex`

Comment: Great answer! So that the comments make sense, let me explain that I edited this to respond to the question (i.e. changed "pdflatex" to "xelatex")

Comment: I'd like to note that after `v8.23.0` magic commands are disabled by default. You can read more [here](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/3027). Basically you have to disable `forceRecipeUsage` in settings if you want to enable them.

Comment: @HirbodBehnam Amazing! I was wondering why it stopped working all of a sudden. Great answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit late in the party, but if someone still needs to set `xelatex` from VS Code LaTeX extension, you are in the right place. Add the following configuration to your VS Code `settings.json`, and voila!

```json
"latex-workshop.latex.recipe.default": "latexmk (xelatex)",
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting errors with the other solutions, apparently because I was using `backend=biber` in my latex code. The following configuration assumes a current MiKTeX setup (including biber) and fixes those problems (also, this does not rely on latexmk). The config uses some inspiration from that of TeXworks.

Inside `latex-workshop.latex.tools`

```
{
    "name": "xelatex",
    "command": "xetex",
    "args": [
        "-undump=xelatex",
        "%DOC%.tex"
    ],
    "env": {}
},
{
    "name": "biber",
    "command": "biber",
    "args": [
        "%DOC%"
    ],
    "env": {}
}
```

Then inside `latex-workshop.latex.recipes` add the recipe:

```
{
    "name": "xelatex ➞ biber ➞ xelatex x 2x",
    "tools": [
        "xelatex",
        "biber",
        "xelatex",
        "xelatex"
    ]
}
```

Happy texing!